# Problems with the header

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

Today I want to set a centered header.

My trial

```
\documentclass[utf8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \chead{ 常州大学本科论文外文翻译 }
 \cfoot{第\thepage 页，共\pages 页}
 \section{introduction}
  my name is 汤书桃
 \newpage
 \section{conclusion }
 I like \latex very much 
\end{document}
```

However, it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: What errors do you get? Plus the LaTeX logo is written `\LaTeX` (case matters)

Comment: @daleif,the header show the section 's captions , not the sentence that I define .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few errors:

- `utf8` should be `UTF8`
- `\pages` is not defined (I don't know what it's supposed to do)
- It's `\LaTeX`, not `\latex`

Here's a working version

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all fields
\fancyhead[C]{常州大学本科论文外文翻译}
\fancyfoot[C]{第\thepage 页，共 页}
\setlength{\headheight}{12.7pt}

\begin{document}

\section{introduction}

 my name is 汤书桃

\newpage

\section{conclusion }

I like \LaTeX{} very much 

\end{document}
```

Of course I removed `\pages`.

[image]

Here is the first page footer

[image]

Comment: ,+1,It goes well .Thanks ,I have learned LaTex for a month that by writing my graduating paper and reading the book "The latex Tutorial ".In  fact,I would like to define the command \page as the pages of my document ,but I don't know how to define .Anyway , thanks for your detailed guide.

Comment: If you are looking for something like 'Page 1 of 5'. So If you want total number of pages in the document, you can have a look at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lastpage. Here is the package lastpage, which could be useful in that case.